# Best way to negate a function in matlab

Tags: matlab, performance, optimization

What is the fastest way to negate a function in matlab?

I need to maximize a certain function; to do this, I apply fmincon on -function. The thing is that the function returns (if requested) also its gradient, so doing

```
fmincon(@(x) -function1(x))
```

won't work. Right now I have implemented a function that negates its arguments, like so

```
function [value, gradient] = negateFunction(functionToNegate, point)

if nargout <= 1
    value = -functionToNegate(point);
elseif nargout == 2
    [value, gradient] = functionToNegate(point);
    value = -value;
    gradient = -gradient;

end
end
```

but it looks to me like a bit of an overkill. Is there a better / faster way?

Comment: Have you tested the performance of your approach? Is it really performing slow? I can't see a big overhead here. I guess you could even leave out the first 'if' case without loosing much performance. `gradient` is calculated in each case in `functionToNegate()`.

Comment: @GeorgW. No, to be fair I haven't tested - but it just seems odd to do it like this. I thought there was a more idiomatic way of doing it :)